# JS: Merge 2 arrays into 1 by matching values

Tags: javascript

I have the following two arrays and need `getDomainLabels` to merge into `getDomains`. I'm having trouble matching the value of `domain` with `name`, then adding `label` and it's value. If there's multiple labels for the same domain, set it into an array.

```
    "getDomainLabels": [
      {
        "domain": "m.quest",
        "label": "blog"
      },
      {
        "domain": "m.quest",
        "label": "portfolio"
      },
      {
        "domain": "t.rehab",
        "label": "saas"
      }
    ]
```

```
    "getDomains": [
      {
        "name": "m.quest",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "t.rehab",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
      },
      {
        "name": "x.x",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
      },
    ]
```

Expected result:

```
    "getDomains": [
      {
        "name": "m.quest",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
        "label: ["blog", "portfolio"]
      },
      {
        "name": "t.rehab",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
        "label: "saas"
      },
      {
        "name": "x.x",
        "autoRenew": false,
        "created": "04/20/2021",
        "expires": "04/20/2022"
      },
    ]
```

The following code is my poor effort to try and figure this out but as I continue to try and solve it myself, I thought I'd ask for help!

```
  const labels = labelData.getDomainLabels;
  const domains = data.getDomains;

  for (const element of labels) {
  // loops through the labels needed to be added
  }
```

EDIT: I'm assuming I need to loop through the labels and find a way to match `domain` with `name` of `getDomains` and merge it in somehow, but I'm new enough to need to ask for help.

Comment: Please add your expected result of your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `filter` for each element of `getDomains`, would recommend to use `Map object` to store `domain` and `label` of  `getDomainLabels` as key-value pairs; which will improve the code performance by reducing the time complexity.

```js
const getDomains = [
  {
    "name": "m.quest",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
  {
    "name": "t.rehab",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
  {
    "name": "x.x",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
];

const getDomainLabels = [
  {
    "domain": "m.quest",
    "label": "blog"
  },
  {
    "domain": "m.quest",
    "label": "portfolio"
  },
  {
    "domain": "t.rehab",
    "label": "saas"
  }
];

const mergeArrays = (domains, labels) => {
  const labelMap = new Map();
  for (const labelObj of labels) {
     const list = labelMap.get(labelObj.domain);
     if (list) {
       list.push(labelObj.label);
     } else {
       labelMap.set(labelObj.domain, [labelObj.label]);
     }
  }
  return domains.map(domain => {
    const list = labelMap.get(domain.name);
      const finalObj = { ...domain };
    if (list) {
      finalObj.label = list.length > 1 ? list : list[0]
    }
    return finalObj;
  });
}

console.log(mergeArrays(getDomains, getDomainLabels));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to find those that have the same name and then use `map` to get the `label` property
Try this one:

```js
   var getDomainLabels = [
            {
                "domain": "m.quest",
                "label": "blog"
            },
            {
                "domain": "m.quest",
                "label": "portfolio"
            },
            {
                "domain": "t.rehab",
                "label": "saas"
            }
        ]
        var getDomains = [
            {
                "name": "m.quest",
            },
            {
                "name": "t.rehab",
            },
            {
                "name": "x.x",
            },
        ]


        var newArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < getDomains.length; i++) {
            var lables = getDomainLabels.filter(t => t.domain == getDomains[i].name).map(t => t.label);
            newArray.push({
                name: getDomains[i].name,
                label: (lables && lables.length > 1) ? lables : lables[0]
            })
        }

        console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const getDomainLabels = [
  {
    "domain": "m.quest",
    "label": "blog"
  },
  {
    "domain": "m.quest",
    "label": "portfolio"
  },
  {
    "domain": "t.rehab",
    "label": "saas"
  }
]

const getDomains = [
  {
    "name": "m.quest",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
  {
    "name": "t.rehab",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
  {
    "name": "x.x",
    "autoRenew": false,
    "created": "04/20/2021",
    "expires": "04/20/2022"
  },
]

const newDomains = getDomains.map((domain) => {
  const matchingLabel = getDomainLabels.filter((label) => label.domain === domain.name);
  const valueNode = matchingLabel && matchingLabel.length > 1 ?
                        matchingLabel.map(ml => ml.label) :
                        matchingLabel.length === 1 ? matchingLabel[0].label : null;
  const returnNode = { ...domain, label: null };
  if(valueNode) {
    returnNode.label = valueNode
  } else {
    delete returnNode.label;
  }
  return returnNode;
})
console.log(getDomains);
console.log(newDomains);
```

Comment: returnNode.label = valueNode; TypeError: Cannot add property label, object is not extensible!

Comment: Try using `returnNode['label'] = valueNode`. This is a temporary fix. You may have to update the Object schema and add `label` property for the accurate fix

Comment: haha ```const woohoo = domains.map(obj=> ({ ...obj, label: null }))``` made it work

Comment: @gfylol not just that, you have to delete `returnNode.label` if it doesnot have a value